# How to set size of the bitmap in ZXing?

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am using ZXing to generate a QR code. This is what my code looks like:

```
public partial class QRPage : ContentPage
{
    public QRPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var stream = DependencyService.Get<IBarcodeService>().ConvertImageStream("nika");
        qrImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
        qrImage.HeightRequest = 200;
        
    }
}
```

And the other part:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(BarcodeService))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class BarcodeService : IBarcodeService
    {
        public Stream ConvertImageStream(string text, int width = 500, int height = 500)
        {
            var barcodeWriter = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter
            {
                Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
                {
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height,
                    Margin = 2
                }
            };

            barcodeWriter.Renderer = new ZXing.Mobile.BitmapRenderer();
            var bitmap = barcodeWriter.Write(text);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml where I'm using the code:

```
<StackLayout Padding="20,30,20,30">
    <Label Text="..." FontSize="Medium "/>
    <Frame VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <Image x:Name="qrImage" WidthRequest="300" />
    </Frame>
    ...
</StackLayout>
```

The problem is, that no matter what do I set as height and width for `ConvertImageStream`, the resulting image is not square, but rather looks like this:

[image]

How can I turn it into a square? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and the image correctly sized:

[image]

I doubled checked by saving it:

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "qrcode.png");
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, fileStream);
}
```

And then pulling it and checking its size:

```
$ adb pull /sdcard/qrcode.png
[100%] /sdcard/qrcode.png
$ identify qrcode.png
qrcode.png PNG 500x500 500x500+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.85KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

My Page code:

```
var image = new Image();
var content = new ContentPage
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
    Title = "ZXingQRCode",
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Children = {
            new Label {
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                Text = "StackOverflow",
                FontSize = 40
            },
            image
        }
    }
};
MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
var stream = DependencyService.Get<IBarcodeService>().ConvertImageStream("https://StackOverflow.com");
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
image.HeightRequest = 250;
```

Update:

It is the `Frame` that you are seeing that is wider then the image, not the image itself. Change the `BackgroundColor` of the Frame

```
<StackLayout Padding="20,30,20,30">
    <Label Text="..." FontSize="Medium" />
    <Frame VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
        <Image x:Name="qrImage" WidthRequest="300" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: any suggestions on why it looks like what I posted in my app?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Can you post your xaml (or code) for that page in your question, or try the page code in my answer first to see if you get the same result as myself...

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze You are seeing the frame that is filling the width of the your `StackLayout` not the `Image`, see my answer update

Comment: why does it have a default white background?